# CloudKit, retrieve user information, such as first name on sign up

Tags: swift, cloudkit

During SignUp on my app, I want to retrieve information, such as first name, from iCloud,I then want to store this in my own cloud kit database. How do I access user information from iCloud, without having to ask the user themselves for these relevant fields?

Answer (score 14):

I was able to get it working with this in XCode 8 iOS 10 beta 2:

```
CKContainer.default().requestApplicationPermission(.userDiscoverability) { (status, error) in
            CKContainer.default().fetchUserRecordID { (record, error) in
                CKContainer.default().discoverUserIdentity(withUserRecordID: record!, completionHandler: { (userID, error) in
                    print(userID?.hasiCloudAccount)
                    print(userID?.lookupInfo?.phoneNumber)
                    print(userID?.lookupInfo?.emailAddress)
                    print((userID?.nameComponents?.givenName)! + " " + (userID?.nameComponents?.familyName)!)
                })
            }
        }
```

Comment: Apparently you are correct that the requestApplicationPermission is required. Without it, the discoverUserIdentity oddly invokes the completion handler with both userID and error parameters nil. However, if you invoke requestApplicationPermission, the user is presented with a very baffling alert question "Allow people using 'app' to look you up by email?"

Comment: For me, the `userID?.lookupInfo?.phoneNumber` and `userID?.lookupInfo?.emailAddress` fields are always nil.

Comment: @ph1lb4 did you ever find out why? I'm getting the same!

Answer (score 2):

Use `CKContainer.discoverUserIdentity(withUserRecordID:)` in combination with `CKContainer.fetchUserRecordID` to get a `CKUserIdentity` object for the current user. You can then use a `PersonNameComponentsFormatter` to get their name from the `nameComponents` property of the identity.

Answer (score 1):

```
let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()

container.fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler { (recordId, error) in
    if error != nil {
      print("Handle error)")
 }else{                                                                        

self.container.discoverUserInfoWithUserRecordID(
        recordId!, completionHandler: { (userInfo, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Handle error")
            }else{
                if let userInfo = userInfo {
                    print("givenName =   \(userInfo.displayContact?.givenName)")
                    print("familyName = \(userInfo.displayContact?.familyName)")
                }else{
                    print("no user info")
                }
            }
          })
         }
        }
```