CKUserIdentity `nameComponents` is Empty
My App requires that the user has and allows iCloud access.  With that access I expect to be able to access the users name.  Yet, the following code produces an empty nameComponents result from CKUserIdentity
        var userParticipantIdentity: CKUserIdentity? = nil

        do {
            let userRecordID    = try await container.userRecordID()
            let userParticipant = try await container.shareParticipant (forUserRecordID: userRecordID)
            userParticipantIdentity = userParticipant.userIdentity
        }
        catch { ... throw ... }     

The resulting userParticipantIdentity.nameComponents returns a PersonNameComponents w/o any name values.
Given that my app requires iCloud access (and that various iOS 'discovery interfaces' have been deprecated), how can I go about getting a user's name?
More specifically, if you create a new Xcode project using CoreData w/ CloudKit and you then add the following to ContentView:
        .task {
            let container = controller.cloudKitContainer

            do { try controller.container.initializeCloudKitSchema() } catch {}

            do {
                let userStatus = try await container.accountStatus()
                guard case .available = userStatus
                else { print ("UserName: Error: No iCloud"); return }

                let userRecordID    = try await container.userRecordID()
                let userParticipant = try await container.shareParticipant(forUserRecordID: userRecordID)
                let userParticipantIdentity = userParticipant.userIdentity

                guard let userParticipantNameComponents = userParticipantIdentity.nameComponents
                else { print ("UserName: Error: No `nameComponents"); return }

                let userParticipantName = PersonNameComponentsFormatter().string(from: userParticipantNameComponents)
                print ("UserName: Got: `\(userParticipantName)`")
            }
            catch {
                print ("UserName: Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

the runtime print out will be "UserName: Got: ``"

Checkout the overview for the documentation for CKUserIdentity. You need to request permission to obtain the actual data.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38290516/cloudkit-retrieve-user-information-such-as-first-name-on-sign-up

@HangarRash All the 'user discoverability' interfaces are deprecated.

I hadn't noticed that CKContainer requestApplicationPermission has been deprecated as of iOS 18. Oddly, the CKContainer.h deprecation info states to have a look at "Sharing CloudKit Data with Other iCloud Users" which is a sample app that doesn't seem related at all to getting user identity or discoverability.

In that sample App the CKUserIdentity is populated with names if and only if a 'share' is accepted by another person.  Then both sides see the names (as 'participants').  In my case there isn't anybody to share with; I'm just looking for the user's own name.

Right. That was my point. The deprecation notes point to a sample app that doesn't help at all. It's weird. I now realize my app has the same issue you are reporting. I support iOS 15+ but now under iOS 18 I don't get the username any more. Ugh.
